# verify certain value does not exists within a dropdown list

Tags: cucumber, watir

I wish to verify a certain value does not exist within a drop down list.

So html is:

```
<select id="delivery" name="delivery" onchange="this.form.submit();">
  <option  selected="selected" value="Del1">Delivey1</option>
</select>
```

So I wish to ensure that when I have certain items in my basket delivery option 2 is not present.

So the code I was trying:

```
result = @browser.select(:id, "delivery").include? ("Delivery2")
assert result = false
```

However this does not work.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, I am guessing that `result` is correct. It looks like the problem is the assertion. Doing the assertion

```
assert result = false
```

is not valid syntax (you cannot do an assignment here).

Try one of the following instead:

```
assert( result == false )  #Note that it is == instead of =
assert_equal( true, result )
```